# Detectando URL em Textarea com Regex

Tags: javascript, regex

Caros,
Gostaria de usar o seguinte exemplo (https://www.regextester.com/96504) que marca qualquer link digitado, e colocar em  uma textarea do meu site para marcar e avisar que não é permitido links.
Testei com *required pattern* e não consegui.
Fiz também o seguinte exemplo mas não funcionou no textarea:

```
function isUrl(s) {
    var regexp = (?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/|\b(?:[a-z\d]+\.))(?:(?:[^\s()<>]+|\((?:[^\s()<>]+|(?:\([^\s()<>]+\)))?\))+(?:\((?:[^\s()<>]+|(?:\(?:[^\s()<>]+\)))?\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:'".,<>?«»“”‘’]))?
    return regexp.test(s);
}
```

Fiz vários outros exemplos mas até agora não consegui. Alguém poderia dar uma pequena ajuda para eu começar.
Antes que alguém mais me negative, fiz muitos exemplos, faz vários dias que estou pesquisando sobre isso, e como não posso colocar todos os meus testes aqui então fui bem direto na primeira pergunta e fui negativado.
Obrigado

Comment: você quer detectar ou marcar?

Comment: Pelo que eu pesquisei aqui você não consegue fazer isso direto no TextArea... vai ter que desenvolver alguma outra solução, pois dentro do TextArea só é aceito texto puro.

Comment: Olá Leonardo, quero somente marcar para o usuário saber que ele está digitando algo inválido no campo textarea.

Answer (score 1):

Veja se eu entendi bem.... executa ai.

```js
// Add your javascript here
$(function(){
  
  function changeColor(parent) {
    var text = parent.text().replace(/\r/g, '');
    var newHTML = "";

    if(/(?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/|\b(?:[a-z\d]+\.))(?:(?:[^\s()<>]+|\((?:[^\s()<>]+|(?:\([^\s()<>]+\)))?\))+(?:\((?:[^\s()<>]+|(?:\(?:[^\s()<>]+\)))?\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:'".,<>?«»“”‘’]))?/.test(text)) {
      newHTML = "<span class='statement'>" + text + "\r</span>";
    } else {
      newHTML = "<span class='other'>" + text + "\r</span>";
    }
    parent.html(newHTML);

    var child = parent.children();
    var range = document.createRange();
    var sel = window.getSelection();
    range.setStart(child[child.length-1], 1);
    range.collapse(true);
    sel.removeAllRanges();
    sel.addRange(range);
    
    parent[0].focus();
  }
  
  changeColor($("#editor"));
  
  $("#editor").on("keydown keyup", function(e){
          changeColor($(this));
  });
});
```

```css
#editor {
    width: 400px;
    height: 100px;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #444;
    color: white;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: monospace;
}
  
.statement {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="editor" contenteditable="true">
</div>
```